# Fliping dictionary key value Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
d = {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 0, 9: 4, 10: 2, 11: 4, 12: 1, 13: 2, 14: 2, 15: 4, 16: 2}
```

I would like to count the number each value appear in the dictionary:
i.e:

```
new_d_count = {0:3, 1:3, 2:7, ...}
```

I would also like to "flip" it such that, each value will be the key, and the value of that new key will be the keys of the original list. 
i.e:

```
new_d = {0:(0,4,8), 1:(1,5,12), 2:(2,6,7,10,13,14,16) .....}
```

Comment: Sounds like you've got a clear idea of what you want to do. What have you tried/what problem are you having?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `Counter` for your first problem:

```
from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(d.values())
Counter({2: 7, 0: 3, 1: 3, 4: 3, 3: 1})
```

Use a `defaultdict` for your second problem:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> new_d = defaultdict(tuple)
>>> for k,v in d.items():
...     new_d[v] += (k,)
... 
>>> new_d
defaultdict(<type 'tuple'>, {0: (0, 4, 8), 1: (1, 5, 12), 2: (2, 6, 7, 10, 13, 14, 16), 3: (3,), 4: (9, 11, 15)})
```

Alternatively, without `defaultdict`:

```
>>> new_d = {}
>>> for k,v in d.items():
...     new_d[v] = new_d.get(v, tuple()) + (k,)
... 
>>> new_d
{0: (0, 4, 8), 1: (1, 5, 12), 2: (2, 6, 7, 10, 13, 14, 16), 3: (3,), 4: (9, 11, 15)}
```

Finally, if you don't really need the values to be tuples, do it like this:

```
>>> new_d = {}
>>> for k,v in d.items():
...     new_d.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
... 
>>> new_d
{0: [0, 4, 8], 1: [1, 5, 12], 2: [2, 6, 7, 10, 13, 14, 16], 3: [3], 4: [9, 11, 15]}
```

Comment: @matlabit no problem, I added another option.